# iOS 12 freezes application

Tags: swift4, freeze, xcode10, ios12

Hello everyone I have a very strange issue with **iOS 12**, my application is a simple table of all the games I did in iOS, the project, I did with **swift 4** for **iOS 11** with **XCode 9**, I use a simple Storyboard with 2 viewcontrollers with tableviews and also includes a Share Extension, everything works normally until **iOS 11.4.1**, now when I upgraded **XCode 10** with **iOS 12**, it worked normally in the simulator and in an **iPhone SE** in debug mode, the problem arose when I uploaded a build to Testflight and the application was installed on an **iPhone 6 Plus**, the screen is completely frozen, the share extension works but the application does not, I saw 2 questions related to this [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519362/view-controller-is-not-responsive-after-upgrading-to-ios-12-freezes) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413278/ios-12-application-freezes-during-start-up), but without answer and that is why I also share my code, this is The initial view controller where is freezed:

```
//  Home.swift
//  MenuGames
//  Created by Dennis Mostajo on 7/3/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 MenuGames. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import Foundation
import MessageUI
import PKHUD
import Toast_Swift

class Home: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
{
let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 6, width: 33, height: 33))
let titleLabel = UILabel(frame:CGRect(x:45, y:12, width:140, height:21))
@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
var reachability: Reachability!
fileprivate var offlineToast: UIView!
var isToastShowing: Bool {
    get {
        return !((self.offlineToast?.isHidden) ?? true)
    }
}

// MARK: - viewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.checkConnections()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.setupCustomNavigationBar()
    self.showNavBarItems()
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.hideNavBarItems()
}
// MARK: - Methods
func setupCustomNavigationBar()
{
    let settings = DataBaseHelper.getSettings(settings_id: 1)
    var themeColor:ThemeColor!
    var imgIcon:UIImage!
    if (settings?.isDefaultThemeColor)!
    {
        themeColor = DataBaseHelper.getThemeColor(theme_color_id: 1)
        let imgBackground = UIImage(named:"background")
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(imgBackground?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0), resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
        imgIcon = UIImage(named:"icon")
    }
    else
    {
        themeColor = DataBaseHelper.getThemeColor(theme_color_id: 2)
        imgIcon = UIImage(named:"darkIcon")
    }
    self.table.separatorColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: themeColor.settings_navigation_text_color)
    self.table.tableFooterView = UIView()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: themeColor.settings_navigation_background_color)
    self.imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    self.imgView.image = imgIcon
    self.titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
    self.titleLabel.textColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: themeColor.settings_navigation_text_color)
    self.titleLabel.text = "Menu Games"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(imgView)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(titleLabel)
}
func showNavBarItems()
{
    self.imgView.isHidden = false
    self.titleLabel.isHidden = false
}
func hideNavBarItems()
{
    self.imgView.isHidden = true
    self.titleLabel.isHidden = true
}
func showAlertGlobally(_ alert: UIAlertController) {
    let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert
    alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
    alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func redirectLogToDocuments() -> String {

    let allPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = allPaths.first!
    let pathForLog: String = documentsDirectory + "/logs.txt"

    return pathForLog
}
func checkConnections()
{
    do {
        reachability = Reachability()
        offlineToast = try self.view.toastViewForMessage(NSLocalizedString("NO_CONNECTION", comment: "You have no connection"), title: "", image: UIImage(named: "icon"), style: ToastStyle())
    } catch {
        debugPrint("Unable to create Reachability")
    }
    guard let _ = reachability, let _ = offlineToast else {
        return
    }

    reachability.whenReachable = { [weak self] reachability in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.offlineToast.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    reachability.whenUnreachable = { [weak self] reachability in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.showConnectiontoast()
            self?.offlineToast.isHidden = false
        }
    }

    do {
        try reachability.startNotifier()
    } catch {
        print("Unable to start notifier")
    }
}
func showConnectiontoast(){
    self.view.showToast(self.offlineToast, duration: TimeInterval.infinity, position: .center) { _ in
        self.showConnectiontoast()
    }
}
func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
// MARK: - MFMailComposeViewController
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                           didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    // Check the result or perform other tasks.

    // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
// MARK: - UITableView
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    var height:CGFloat = 0
    if tableView == self.table
    {
        height = 25
    }
    return height
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    var height:CGFloat = 0
    if tableView == self.table
    {
        height = 50
    }
    return height
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    var sections:Int = 0
    if tableView == self.table
    {
        sections = 2
    }
    return sections
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    var rows:Int = 0
    if tableView == self.table
    {
        switch section
        {
        case 0:
            rows = 2
            break
        case 1:
            rows = 4
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    return rows
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    let settings = DataBaseHelper.getSettings(settings_id: 1)
    var themeColor:ThemeColor!
    if (settings?.isDefaultThemeColor)!
    {
        themeColor = DataBaseHelper.getThemeColor(theme_color_id: 1)
    }
    else
    {
        themeColor = DataBaseHelper.getThemeColor(theme_color_id: 2)
    }
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 25))
    headerView.backgroundColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: themeColor.settings_header_section_background_color)
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 25))
    label.textColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: themeColor.settings_header_section_text_color)
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
    headerView.addSubview(label)
    if (section == 0) {
        label.text = NSLocalizedString("GENERAL_TITLE", comment: "General Title Section")
    } else {
        label.text = NSLocalizedString("HELP_TITLE", comment: "Help Title Section")
    }
    return headerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let settings = DataBaseHelper.getSettings(settings_id: 1)
    var themeColor:ThemeColor!
    if (settings?.isDefaultThemeColor)!
    {
        themeColor = DataBaseHelper.getThemeColor(theme_color_id: 1)
    }
    else
    {
        themeColor = DataBaseHelper.getThemeColor(theme_color_id: 2)
    }
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.backgroundColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: themeColor.settings_cell_background_color)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: themeColor.settings_cell_text_color)
    let cellHighLighting = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.bounds.size.width, height: cell.bounds.size.height))
    cellHighLighting.image = UIImage(named: "Frame")
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellHighLighting
    if tableView == self.table
    {
        switch indexPath.section
        {
        case 0      :
            switch indexPath.row
            {
            case 0:
                cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString("ACCOUNT_TITLE", comment: "Account Title Row")
                break
            case 1:
                cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString("GAME_TITLE", comment: "Game Title Row")
                break
            default:
                break
            }
            break
        case 1      :
            switch indexPath.row
            {
            case 0:
                cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString("ABOUT_TITLE", comment: "About Title Row")
                break
            case 1:
                cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString("REPORT_TITLE", comment: "Report Title Row")
                break
            case 2:
                cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString("TUTORIAL_TITLE", comment: "Tutorial Title Row")
                break
            case 3:
                cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString("FEATURES_TITLE", comment: "Features Title Row")
                break
            default:
                break
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if tableView == self.table
    {
        switch indexPath.section
        {
        case 0:
            switch indexPath.row
            {
            case 0:
                let user = DataBaseHelper.getUser()
                let user_type = DataBaseHelper.getUserTypeById(user_type_id: (user?.user_type_id)!)
                if (user_type?.name == "REGISTERED")||(user_type?.name == "PAID")
                {
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AccountVc") as! AccountVc
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                }
                else
                {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Menu Games", message: NSLocalizedString("IF_USER_NOT_LOGIN", comment: "if user not login"), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("SIGNUP", comment: "sign up"), style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                        debugPrint("sign up")
                        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVc") as! LoginVc
                        vc.isForLogin = false
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                    }))
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("LOGIN", comment: "login"), style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                        debugPrint("login")
                        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVc") as! LoginVc
                        vc.isForLogin = true
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                    }))
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("CANCEL", comment: "cancel"), style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                        debugPrint("cancel")
                    }))
                    self.showAlertGlobally(alert)
                }
                break
            case 1:
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameVc") as! GameVc
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                break
            default:
                break
            }
            break
        case 1:
            switch indexPath.row
            {
            case 0:
                let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String
                let build = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"] as! String
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Menu Games", message: String(format: "Version:%@\nBuild:%@",version,build), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                    debugPrint("OK")
                }))
                self.showAlertGlobally(alert)
                break
            case 1:
                let toEmail = "support@menugames.com"
                let subject = NSLocalizedString("REPORTED_TITLE_MESSAGE", comment: "Reported Title Message")
                let deviceName = UIDevice.current.model
                let country = "" //Not Today
                let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)

                var appVersion = "N/A"
                if let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
                    appVersion = version
                }

                var appBuild = "N/A"
                if let build = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
                {
                    appBuild = build
                }

                let osVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
                let body = "Device: \(deviceName) \n Country: \(country) \n Date: \(date) \n App Version: \(appVersion) \n App Build: \(appBuild) \n OS Version: \(osVersion) \n"

                if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {

                    let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
                    composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
                    composeVC.setToRecipients([toEmail])
                    composeVC.setSubject(subject)
                    composeVC.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: false)
                    if let filePath = redirectLogToDocuments() as String?
                    {
                        if let fileData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
                        {
                            composeVC.addAttachmentData(fileData, mimeType: "text/plain", fileName: "user_report.txt")
                        }
                        self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }

                }
                break
            case 2:
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TutorialVc") as! TutorialVc
                vc.isFromDelegate = false
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                break
            case 3:
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FeaturesVc") as! FeaturesVc
                vc.isFromDelegate = false
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                break
            default:
                break
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }

    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}}
```

just in case, I also updated the **iPhone 6 Plus** with **iOS 12.1** in Beta version but the same problem arises, the Testflight Build is frozen for that device

So any help?, or what else can I do to find the source of the problem or what I'm missing or doing wrong? Thank you very much

**EDIT 1:** As @Sulthan suggested I tried to disable Reachability and toasts, all logs printed are:

```
2018-10-03 11:55:50.203071-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011859]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2018-10-03 11:55:50.245379-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011795] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
"applicationWillResignActive"
2018-10-03 11:55:50.406678-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011795] [Crashlytics] Version 3.10.5 (130)
"--->DBUpdate"
2018-10-03 11:55:50.528725-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011868] Version 3.10.0 of Realm is now available: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/v3.10.0/CHANGELOG.md
"--->Path to realm file:Optional(\"This is confidential XD")"
initializeFCM
2018-10-03 11:55:50.595893-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011868] 5.5.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.50100000 started
2018-10-03 11:55:50.632665-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011858] Failed to create remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2018-10-03 11:55:50.632679-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011795] Failed to create synchronous remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2018-10-03 11:55:50.633502-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011795] [NetworkInfo] Descriptors query returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2018-10-03 11:55:50.634345-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011795] Failed to create synchronous remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2018-10-03 11:55:50.633217-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011858] Failed to ping server after delegate was set
2018-10-03 11:55:50.634761-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011795] [NetworkInfo] Descriptors query returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2018-10-03 11:55:50.635606-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011795] Failed to create synchronous remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2018-10-03 11:55:50.636167-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011795] [NetworkInfo] Descriptors query returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}
2018-10-03 11:55:50.621618-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011868] 5.5.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
2018-10-03 11:55:50.651866-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011868] 5.5.0 - [Firebase/Crash][I-CRA000004] Successfully initialized
"AppDelegate: launch"
"Home: viewdidload"
"applicationDidBecomeActive"
2018-10-03 11:55:50.973891-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011795] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is This is confidential XD
2018-10-03 11:55:50.974605-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011795] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2018-10-03 11:55:51.953420-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011877] TIC TCP Conn Failed [7:0x600001641bc0]: 12:8 Err(-65554)
2018-10-03 11:55:51.962866-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011877] Task <C4C960B3-82CD-4034-94AA-14F815ADD9E2>.<4> HTTP load failed (error code: -1003 [12:8])
2018-10-03 11:55:51.963445-0400 Menu Games[30260:1011877] Task <C4C960B3-82CD-4034-94AA-14F815ADD9E2>.<4> finished with error - code: -1003
```

and about the View UI Heriarchy there is not nothing overlaping:
[image]

As I said before, it still running on **iOS 11** properly and in a Debug way, but when I upload a build on Testflight and run in a real device with **iOS 12** specifically an **iPhone 6 Plus** no

**EDIT 2:** Continuing with the suggestions of @Sulthan, I updated my noob error of super.viewWillAppear (animated) in viewWillDisappear, then according to the Toast Pod only userInteractionEnabled is used when displaying the Toast but with all enabled:

```
// MARK: - Private Show/Hide Methods

    private func showToast(_ toast: UIView, duration: TimeInterval, point: CGPoint) {
        toast.center = point
        toast.alpha = 0.0

        if ToastManager.shared.isTapToDismissEnabled {
            let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIView.handleToastTapped(_:)))
            toast.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
            toast.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            toast.isExclusiveTouch = true
        }

        activeToasts.add(toast)
        self.addSubview(toast)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: ToastManager.shared.style.fadeDuration, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
            toast.alpha = 1.0
        }) { _ in
            let timer = Timer(timeInterval: duration, target: self, selector: #selector(UIView.toastTimerDidFinish(_:)), userInfo: toast, repeats: false)
            RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
            objc_setAssociatedObject(toast, &ToastKeys.timer, timer, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
```

My AppDelegate is also very simple since I just added Firebase before **iOS 12** comes out:

```
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  MenuGames
//  Created by Dennis Mostajo on 7/3/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 MenuGames. All rights reserved.
//
import UIKit
import Fabric
import Crashlytics
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{
    var window: UIWindow?
    var navigationVC: UINavigationController?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        debugPrint("applicationWillResignActive")
        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
        DataBaseHelper.DBUpdate() // Run migrations
        self.initializeFCM(_application: application)
        debugPrint("AppDelegate: launch")
        return true
    }
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        debugPrint("applicationWillResignActive")
    }
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        debugPrint("applicationDidEnterBackground")
    }
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        debugPrint("applicationWillEnterForeground")
    }
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)
    {
        debugPrint("applicationDidBecomeActive")
    } 
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        debugPrint("applicationWillTerminate")
    }
        // MARK: - FIREBASE
    func initializeFCM(_application:UIApplication)
    {
        print("initializeFCM")
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
    }
}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID
            {
                (result, error) in
                if let error = error
                {
                    debugPrint("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
                }
                else if let result = result
                {
                    debugPrint("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
                }
            }
        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    }
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

In Instruments the threads show when I call to use the realm database and init:
[image]

And Still freezing on **iPhone 6 Plus** T_T

Comment: Well, I would try to 1. disable `Reachiblity` 2. disable toasts 3. check what is run in debugger as the last statement (or using logs) 4. check UI in view debugger whether there are some overlapping views or something.

Comment: Thanks, @Sulthan, I tried but stills freezing (Edit 1)

Comment: I am also thinking it could be a deadlock. I see that you are accessing a lot of database things from UI. It could happen there is some `DispatchQueue.main.sync` in there, therefore deadlocking?

Comment: Thanks again @Sulthan, I have checked again on Instruments(debug and release version), there are little threads about Realm based on Init the configuration, But I don't think that will block the Main Thread, all seems clean

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not enough code to reproduce the issue. My guess is either a deadlock or that your are blocking user interaction somehow (e.g. a controller presentation that does not succeed,  or explicitely using `UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()` or `view.userInteractionEnabled = false`). The only error I have noticed is that you are calling `super.viewWillAppear(animated)` in `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: I added more details in the Edit 2 @Sulthan, but I honestly do not know what else it could be, thank you very much anyway